# SharePoint 2010 : HTTP/1.1 200 OK but Connection Close

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

Before, I managed to access the URL `http://spn_v1:15778`. But after my Active Directory restarted, I cannot access this URL. I got error

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/9.8 
>   Date: Wed, 04 Feb 2015 08:42:13 GMT
>   Connection: close

I open the log and I found this message.

[image]

For info, when I created a new Web Application with different URL and port, I managed to access the application without any error.

I tried to use the available solution here, but still didn't work.

EDIT------

### I have tried to detach the content database for that web application and attach again. But still didn't work.

EDIT ---

### I tried to create new site collection in same web application. The result i can access the URL which is http://spn_v1:15573/sites/tms/default.aspx.. But when i try access URL http: //spn_v1:15573, it is still display same error (Connection Close). How could i use the URL? (http://spn_v1:15573)

Comment: Any chance that port is used by something else? Did you try IIS reset?

Comment: @luccio, I think no.I've reset the IIS and still display same error which is connection close..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I what you can do for a test is to remove the current Content Database that is beneath the Web Application. This should be the Site Collection that holds the Root Site Collection. This means "/" Site Collection.

Create a new temporary content database under the Web Application, and create a new Site Collection. If the problem is persisted remove the web application and create a new one.

Comment: if i create new web application meaning that i need to create again site collection and page which i have created before?

Comment: Yes, you have too... just for confirmation. Sometimes something goes wrong. Or your page has been checked out with another account, or is by accident deleted?

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem is to create new site in the same farm. The new URL will be http://spn_v1:15778/sites/newsite. But unfortunately i cannot uses the root URL "http://spn_v1:15778" .

Thank for your help and feedback @pipelinecache